# How to effectively set the textsize in webview in Android?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am giving a html string to the WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL() method.I have used  webSettings.setDefaultFontSize((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txtSize)) to set the text size of webview.But on different devices text is rendered very differently.On small devices text is rendered too small and on large devices text is rendered very large.How to effectively set the text size in webview android?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it works with webViews but it works with normal TextView:
That is because setDefaultFontSize() uses Pixel. Use Scale-Independent-Pixel ( sp ) http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

```
public int SpToPx(int sp) {
return sp * this.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
}
```

Comment: @ff17x3-sorry but this did not work for me.I think I might be using it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You supplying HTML and trying to style it, so use the tool for the job, which is CSS.  Specify the size in pixels (`px`) because "[a CSS “pixel” actually takes into account the device pixel ratio](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/pixelperfect)".